# resolv.conf keeps getting overwritten when dnsmasq is restarted, breaking dnsmasq

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns, dnsmasq

I'm running Debian Jessie and I'm trying to configure dnsmasq as a caching DNS server. I used a [guide](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/09/18/caching-nameserver-using-dnsmasq/) to come up with the following `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-hosts
dns-forward-max=150
cache-size=1000
neg-ttl=3600
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
no-poll
```

Doing `sudo service dnsmasq restart` fails and it won't start, telling me

```
Mar 26 17:13:01 user dnsmasq[26743]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Mar 26 17:13:01 user dnsmasq[26746]: dnsmasq: only one resolv.conf file allowed in no-poll mode.
```

Ok, kind of strange that a config straight out of a guide failed. I'll just remove the `no-poll` option to see if it works. This time it starts just fine, but DNS resolution is clearly failing. Relevant files:

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

`/etc/resolv.dnsmasq`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

The third file appears to be dnsmasq's live resolv.conf file, because adding a nameserver line to it while dnsmasq is already running causes DNS resolution to immediate start working. So it looks like it ignored my `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq`. I also tried adding a nameserver line to my `/etc/resolv.conf` and removing the `resolv-file` line in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but it gets overwritted immediately to what you see above upon doing `sudo service dnsmasq restart`.

What is going on with dnsmasq and do I configure dnsmasq as a caching DNS server?

Comment: If you just want a static server, why don't you put `server=8.8.8.8` in your dnsmasq config?

Comment: I'm thinking the `no-poll` basically says to ignore the `resolv-file`.  At startup, it takes whichever file is newer, so that will be `/etc/resolv.conf` in your case (because it gets rewritten when something changes).

Comment: I still don't know what the correct way to do it would be if I had more than one DNS server in mind, but since I don't I'll just be happy that your remark solved my issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the start-up script for `dnsmasq` that uses `resolvconf` to clobber the local resolver if the local loopback interface is not explicitly `except`-ed in the `/etc/defaults/dnsmasq` file.

The short answer is that you can add...

```
DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo
```

to `/etc/defaults/dnsmasq` to solve the problem.

For more info, see this question...

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/proper-way-to-prevent-dnsmasq-from-overwriting-dns-server-list-supplied-by-dhcp

Comment: This saved my life.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

bigjosh is right - except there's been an update to dnsmasq, and there's now an option at the end of `/etc/default/dnsmasq` which you can un-hash:

```
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
```

Comment: This is how it works with my complex setup on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: bigjosh's way worked for me. Even though `/etc/defaults/dnsmasq` had `IGNORE_RESOLVECONF=yes` with instructions to uncomment it to solve this issue, which it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
```

Put dns server into dnsmasq.conf, like

```
server=/localnet/192.168.0.1 # change ip for your ip-server
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

And add into dnsmasq.conf

```
no-resolv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a caching-only DNS server and nothing else fancy that dnsmasq can do, you'd be better off installing either `lwresd` or `unbound` and using the stock default configuration which gives you a caching-only DNS server.  Then you just set `/etc/resolv.conf` to use "nameserver 127.0.0.1" and you're done.

The nice thing is these two packages do not mess around with what's in `/etc/resolv.conf` like dnsmasq does and is thus a cleaner solution IMHO.  You can also usually remove the `resolvconf` package so nothing messes around with `/etc/resolv.conf`.

FYI, dnsmasq has gotten rather complicated, too many bells and whistles and is just causing pain for most people anymore.  Violates KISS in my book.

Comment: Unfortunately, some packages depend on `dnsmasq-base`, like `network-manager` and `libvirt-bin` (if you're doing KVM), so it's not always possible to completely get rid of it.  In that case, you can delete `/usr/sbin/dnsmaq` and make it a hard-link to `/bin/true` so it always succeeds (to fool the init script)  Then `chattr +i /usr/sbin/dnsmasq` to lock it from being updated.  I've had to do this on several laptops.

Comment: +1 as well described in http://www.philandstuff.com/2013/11/07/dnsmasq-resolvconf.html . Reallly disgusting behavior and keeps causing pain even 5 years after the post and bug report...